# concurrent.futures, selenium and tkinter freeze problem

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, selenium, tkinter, threadpoolexecutor

I have a problem which I cannnot understand with these libraries.

My main code looks like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import concurrent.futures
from news_bar import NewsBar        
from fbscout import FbScout         #it bases on sellenium

def run():
    scout.login(USER_EMAIL, USER_PASS)

    while True:
        news = str(scout.check_news())
        if news:
            news_bar.add_text(news)

if __name__ == "__main__":
root = tk.Tk()
news_bar = NewsBar(root)
scout = FbScout.Scrpper()
scout.set_groups(GROUPS)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    gui = executor.submit(news_bar.mainloop())
    sc = executor.submit(scout.run_browser())
    run = executor.submit(run())
```

The program freezes and do not execute the rest of a code after running a tkinter's gui mainloop.

```
gui = executor.submit(news_bar.mainloop())
```

I don't know how to order the program not to wait until infinite loop execute... When I close the tkinter's window it comes the right way further

COMMENT:
To sum up. I have two functions news_bar.mainloop() which is waiting for an event and and run() which is infinite loop. And I want them to work simultaneously and independent form each other.

Comment: `While True:`,How do you break it?

Comment: I don't. Program is during creation. I added these lines to see if everything work's fine. But it still doesn't... and even does not come to these lines until I do not close the tkinter's gui window.

Comment: You need use another thread to use `for` loop to run your `add_text`

Comment: Even if I am doing so, threads are still blocked by gui thread...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works! Needed to create a new class which inherited the first main tkinter class and inside of which was placed the selenium base module.

```
class FbBar(NewsBar):
def __init__(self, master):
    NewsBar.__init__(self, master)
    scout = FbScout.Scrpper()
    scout.set_groups(GROUPS)
    self.update()
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.prepare_browser, args=[scout])
    t.start()

@staticmethod
def prepare_browser(scout):
    scout.run_browser()
    scout.login(USER_EMAIL, USER_PASS)



root = tk.Tk()
news_bar = FbBar(root)
news_bar.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The mainloop function is not finished until you close your window (assuming you haven't passed an argument).

Maybe another thread will solve your problem?

Comment: Well, I have added the thread which is responsible for checking_for update in infinite loop also. But the mainloop still requires an event and do not allow to proceed the remaining threads.